# Ellipsis filter vueJs

Tags: javascript, dom, vuejs2, vue.js

I'm rendering dynamically a text content into a dom element with Vue.JS

```
<article>{{ movie.summary }}</article>
```

what I'm trying to achieve is creating an auto-ellipsis filter so I would basically write this :

```
<article>{{ movie.summary | ellipsis({maxLines: 6}) }}</article>
```

for example.

The problem with that is that I need informations about the article DOM element to calculate line-height, height, width etc...

I can't figure out how to retrieve these in a clean way and I don't want to use a dependency / plugin to achieve that.

Is there a way to get dom information about filtered content element ?
Should I use another approach ?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: For anyone looking for this feature, can try [vue-ellipsis](https://github.com/jypblue/vue-ellipsis)

Answer (score 1):

You should use [ref](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#v-el-and-v-ref-replaced) attribute to get the DOM element.
and also use [computed properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Basic-Example) instead of filters , it's a better practice.

Comment: Thanks for the ref, but how computed properties are a better practice in this case in particular ? I'm just manipulating a string, exactly the purpose of filter.

Comment: @cprune since they are half-way deprecated [in version 2](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#Filters)